# what is host property in directives and how to know this details

Tags: angular, angular8

Hi I using angular 8 with ng-bootstrap to add table in my project
I find this code that I didn't understand very well

```
  @Directive({
  selector: 'th[sortable]',
  host: {
    '[class.asc]': 'direction === "asc"',
    '[class.desc]': 'direction === "desc"',
    '(click)': 'rotate()'
    }
  })
```

can anyone tell me what the code say?
and what "th" mean in selector.
also host can i change it to something else because the editor say that, is it Old property or what

Thanks to all

Answer (score 10):

As per Angular [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#directive):

**selector**

> selector: The CSS selector that identifies this directive in a template and triggers instantiation of the directive.

So in your code `selector: 'th[sortable]'` selector declares select by `th` element name with `[sortable]` attribute. You should find something like `<th sortable>...` in your html file.

*UPDATE to answer the comment*:
As per [link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#sortable) shared in comment, here is the `th sortable` in html code:
[image]

**host**

> host: Maps class properties to host element bindings for properties, attributes, and events, using a set of key-value pairs.

```js
host: {
    [key: string]: string;
}
```

It's preferable to use `@HostBinding` and `@HostListener` instead of `host` by angular style guide, check [this link](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#hostlistenerhostbinding-decorators-versus-host-metadata) for more details.

To replace `host` in your code:

`@HostBinding` allows you to set properties on the element or component that hosts the directive. So it will replace your `[class.asc]` and `[class.desc]` code with the following **inside your directive**:

```js
@HostBinding('class.asc') direction = 'asc';

@HostBinding('class.desc') direction = 'desc';
```

`@HostListener` allows you to listen for events on the host element or component. So your `'(click)'` code will be replaced with the following **inside your directive**:

```js
@HostListener('click') rotate() { 
  // todo:  
}
```

Comment: I didn't find** <th sortable> **element in HTML code. I will give you the link for example table and can you tell me what I should to change. <br>[link](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#sortable)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should understand what's the difference between a **directive** and a **component**.

**Unlike components**, directives do not require a view. They should be responsible for rendering logic: `adding`/`removing` elements and/or adding **custom behavior** to DOM elements or components.

`th[sortable]` - think of it as a normal `CSS selector`. This would be translated into: A `th` element with a `sortable` attribute: `<th sortable></th>`.
If the selector was comma-separated(`th,[sortable]`) it would mean that you either use your directive as `th` or `<any-comp sortable></any-comp>` or `<th sortable></th>`.

The `host` property, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive)

> Maps class properties to host element bindings for properties, attributes, and events, using a set of key-value pairs.

where the `host element` is the element/component you have attached your directive to.

However, you can achieve the same results by using [`HostBinding`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostBinding) and [`HostListener`](https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener).

With this in mind, you code could look like this:

```js
@Directive({ ... })
export class YourAwesomeDirective {
 @HostBinding('class.asc')
 get ascClass () {
  return this.direction === 'asc';
 }

 @HostBinding('class.desc')
 get descClass () {
  return this.direction === 'desc';
 }

 @HostListener('click', '[$event]')
 onClick (ev) { /* ... */ }
}
```