# HostListener and HostBinding do not remove original listener or original binding when used in a directive

Tags: angular

When creating a directive with `HostListener` or `HostBinding` and attaching it to a component or HTML element, the original listener or binding are not modified.

Reading this post (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58567228/7365461) would lead me to believe that the original binding and original event listener would be replaced by the directive's `HostListener` and `HostBinding` but this is not the case as can be seen in this StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kxpk7m?file=src%2Fapp%2Frandom.directive.ts&file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html.

When applying the `random` directive to the hello component, both the directive and component's click event handlers are ran. Changing the `name` input also has no effect with `HostBinding`.

Does anybody know how I can remove the original event handlers and property bindings of `@Input()`s?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So, if an html element has a click event binded to it or anyother event . Binding another click event won't erase previous click event

So what you wanna do is

```
const listenersArray = getEventListeners(elementRef);
```

This would give you an an object like this:

```
{ click: [ listener ] };
```

Then you can iterate over listeners on the click property
and go like

```
if ( listenersArray?.click ) {
  listenersArray?.click.forEach( listener => {
    elementRef.removeEventListener( listener );
  }
}
```

**NOTE:** You might wanna do it in constructor or onInit before you hostBinding binds to click or it might remove hostbinding listener too